# Are there any stable native threading APIs for Android?

Tags: multithreading, android-ndk

I am going to make an android game engine, primary using native C++.
I want to use threading and I don't want to implement it in Java, because of the JNI's slowness. Are there any stable native threading APIs for Android, I could use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some research on the topic (threading support in Android NDK) today, and it seems the options are as follows:

1. C++11 has native threading support on Android
2. Posix Threads (aka pthread).
3. Boost is available on Android, and includes threading support.
4. Poco is available on Android, and includes threading support.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pthreads` in `libpthread`

Comment: They don't mention libpthread here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html. Is it part of the libc library?

Comment: @MartinErhardt it appears to be part of libc/bionic (<< not an android dev). just `#include <pthread.h>`.

Comment: thank you for support I just found a great tutorial on this topic:http://android.wooyd.org/JNIExample/files/JNIExample.pdf

Comment: Also check out the docs/STABLE-APIS.html file in NDK. It says "Note that the Android C library includes support for pthread (<pthread.h>), so "LOCAL_LIBS := -lpthread" is not needed. The same is true for real-time extensions (-lrt on typical Linux distributions)."

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the threads (Boost.Thread) of [Boost for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119201/how-link-with-static-boost-libraries-for-android).

> I don't want to implement it in Java, because of the JNI's slowness

According to the first post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372899/android-nativeactivity), going native is not always going to make your code run faster (you may be still calling Java code from your C++ under the hood).

Comment: 1. Where shall I know from that the Boost library also contain Threading APIs, if I am not aware of Desktop C++ libraries(no reason for downvoting) 2. Did I say going native makes your code run always faster? - I am just afraid of calling a C function from Java each time the Java-Thread loops through(even if I may be still calling Java code from your C++ under the hood)

Comment: I didn't understand your comment 1. -- I was just proposing the Boost threads, didn't mean to insult you or anything. The only definitive answer to performance problems is to profile your program, so that you know what really takes time. Maybe you can run a small test with JNI and with C++, this will show you what's best for your needs.

Comment: Also not sure why the down-vote. . . 1. Boost or Poco are both options. 2. The stated reason for not using Java is because of JNI slowness, and you did address this fairly in your answer.